# Laptop monitor looks like "TV with no signal" after battery discharge

Tags: 20.04, monitor

After my laptop unload the battery, the monitor looked like this. Is not the hardware because when I turn on the laptop, it gives me image on this monitor. After the crypto password, the images gets out.

Display settings:

[image: Display settings screenshot]

Monitor picture:

[image: Monitor picture]

```
➜  ~ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   2560x1080     59.98*+  74.99    50.00  
   3840x2160     29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     75.00    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
eDP-1-0 connected 1280x720+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01 +
   1680x1050     60.01  
   1280x1024     60.01  
   1440x900      60.01  
   1280x800      60.01  
   1280x720      60.01* 
   1024x768      60.01  
   800x600       60.01  
   640x480       60.01
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Your display settings screenshot shows resolution 1280x720 however xrandr doesn't report any display with this resolution. Maybe you just need to adjust your Display Settings?

Comment: I already have changed configurations and nothing.